# One line IF condition in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql

It's possible to write one line if's in pl/sql? I'm just curious.

I want to write this snippet:

```
IF ( i.DECISAO_AT = 'S')
THEN 'PA'
ELSE 'I'
END IF;
```

And I want to know if it's possible to write it in one line, just like java. Like this:

```
IF ( i.DECISAO_AT = 'S') ? 'PA' : 'I' ;
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can do that in plsql editor , if you want there is beautifier that can organize the line into several

Comment: Engine parses SQL, weather it's on one line or 50, the engine doesn't care.  separate lines are for human readability.  Put the 4 lines in your example in 1 without changing code and see what happens.

Comment: @xQbert I didn't ask this because optimization or code readability. As I said, I just asked for curiousity.

Comment: And I basically said, yep it will work in 1 line provided you have proper spaces in the syntax `IF ( i.DECISAO_AT = 'S') THEN 'PA' ELSE 'I' END IF;`

Comment: @xQbert in that case, you did'nt understand my question :)

Comment: @TCMSSS do you still have anything not clear so we can help ?

Comment: @TCMSSS then I really don't get the question at all.  I can say you can re-write your query in ORACLE to be `select decode(i.decisao_AT,'S','PA','I') from dual;`  but all this becomes is just different syntax for the same thing. [Oracle Docs on Decode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)  Decode is syntax for if then else, without the if then else.  it could also be done as `case when i.decisao_at='S' then 'PA' else 'I' end`  but as I'm still not sure what you're after, I don't know if any of the above is relevant.

Answer (score 15):

You can write an `IF ... ELSE ... END IF;` on one line as others have shown; but no, you cannot do what you suggested and write it "just like Java":

```
IF ( i.DECISAO_AT = 'S') ? 'PA' : 'I' ;
```

PL/SQL does not understand the Java `?` and `:` syntax, and does not have its own ternary operators as such. You can only use [what is described in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm). The closest thing to what I think you're asking, for this particular statement anyway, is probably a `case`:

```
CASE WHEN i.DECISAO_AT = 'S' THEN 'PA' ELSE 'I' END
```

Or maybe a `decode`, as xQbert already suggested in a comment. Neither is an "IF" any more though.

Comment: Maybe save a couple of characters with CASE i.DECISAO_AT WHEN 'S' THEN 'PA' ELSE 'I' END

Comment: finally someone explained me what I really was asking. Thank you so much Alex Poole

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem in `PL/SQL` executing the code if it was in one line or several lines . What it matters the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `DECODE` statement that you can use inline:
The syntax for the DECODE function in Oracle/PLSQL is:

`DECODE( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] )`

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, but down the road when you need to debug that if with several tests it will be a pain.  Keep it on separate lines, thus easier to read, debug, comment and easier (and thus cheaper) for maintenance down the road.  The next guy to work on it will thank you.

I read in a book (I think it was "C elements of style") once: "beware of clever, clever kills").  Keep it simple and easy.  Code for the guy after you that has to maintain your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DECODE together with a SELECT INTO as below. "my_var" would be a variable declared to hold the decoded value.

```
SELECT DECODE(i.DECISAO_AT, 'S', 'PA', 'I') INTO my_var FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Can you add a description of the solution?